# Why Fastlane lanes from jenkins throwing PhaseScriptExecution [CP] Embed Pods Frameworks error?

Tags: ios, fastlane

Using Fastlane with **upload_build_to_testflight** lane getting a ** ARCHIVE FAILED ** error with error Running script 'PhaseScriptExecution [CP]\ Embed\ Pods\ Frameworks we aren't able to do further process on the build as it's stuck at **gym** using **Jenkins**

By configuring these three files as mentioned below it's working fine on terminal but getting these errors from Jenkins only

**(1) .env.default
(2) AppFile
(3) Fastfile**

Please refer screenshots of **ARCHIVE FAILED**

[image]

This is how we got error on **gym** in Fastfile

[image]

Here is the configuration files which i have set:

**.env.default** file:

```
KEY_ID=“T43C5ACB3B”
ISSUER_ID=“11a2de5e-3c33-47g3-f055-5t8f7d33a6d3”
KEY_FILEPATH="./AuthKey_T43C5ACB3B.p8"
FASTLANE_KEYCHAIN_PATH="/Users/jenkins/Library/Keychains/login.keychain-db"
FASTLANE_KEYCHAIN_PASSWORD= “abcdef”
FASTLANE_PASSWORD = “password”
FASTLANE_APPLE_APPLICATION_SPECIFIC_PASSWORD= “password”
TEAM_ID=“TEAMID”
ITC_TEAM_ID=“456456”

FASTLANE_USER= test@gmail.com
FASTLANE_TEAM_NAME=Team Inc.
FASTLANE_ITC_TEAM_NAME=Team Inc.

PRODUCE_APP_IDENTIFIER=com.fastlane.app
PRODUCE_APP_NAME= TestFastlane
PRODUCE_VERSION=1.1
PRODUCE_SKU=fastlanetest
PRODUCE_PLATFORMS=ios
PRODUCE_LANGUAGE=en-US
APP_WORKSPACE=“Fastlane.xcworkspace"
APP_SCHEME=“Fastlane”
TARGET=“Fastlane”
PROVISIONING_PROFILES=“fast lane” 
XCODEPROJ=“Fastlane.xcodeproj"
CERTIFICATE="Apple Distribution: Fastlane Solutions, Inc. (TEAMID)”
```

**AppFile**

```
require('dotenv')
Dotenv.load '../.env.default'

app_identifier ENV["PRODUCE_APP_IDENTIFIER"] # The bundle identifier of your app
```

**Fastfile**

```
# This file contains the fastlane.tools configuration
# You can find the documentation at https://docs.fastlane.tools
#
# For a list of all available actions, check out
#
#     https://docs.fastlane.tools/actions
#
# For a list of all available plugins, check out
#
#     https://docs.fastlane.tools/plugins/available-plugins
#

# Uncomment the line if you want fastlane to automatically update itself
# update_fastlane

default_platform(:ios)

platform :ios do

  profile_name = nil
  app_identifier =  "#{ENV["PRODUCE_APP_IDENTIFIER"]}"
  app_schema = "#{ENV["APP_SCHEME"]}"
  app_certificate = "#{ENV["CERTIFICATE"]}"

desc "Description of what the lane does"
  lane :load_asc_api_key do
  api_key = app_store_connect_api_key(
     key_id: "#{ENV["KEY_ID"]}",
     issuer_id: "#{ENV["ISSUER_ID"]}",
     key_filepath: "#{ENV["KEY_FILEPATH"]}"
    #  in_house: false # detecting this via ASC private key not currently supported
   )
#   pilot(api_key: api_key)
 end

  lane :create_app_on_store do
  load_asc_api_key
  produce(
    username: CredentialsManager::AppfileConfig.try_fetch_value(:apple_id),
    app_identifier: app_identifier,
    enable_services: {
     push_notification: "on",                  # Valid values: "on", "off"
     associated_domains: "on",
     in_app_purchase: "on"
    }
  )
  end

lane :create_appicon do
  appicon(
    appicon_image_file: '1024.png',
    appicon_devices: [:ipad, :iphone, :ios_marketing],
    appicon_path: "Fastlane/FastlaneImage Assest/WhitelabelledApp.xcassets"
   )
end

desc "Bump build number based on most recent TestFlight build number"
lane :fetch_and_increment_build_number do
 #fetch read your app identifier defined in your Appfile
 api_key = lane_context[SharedValues::APP_STORE_CONNECT_API_KEY]
 
 current_version = get_version_number(
    xcodeproj: "#{ENV["XCODEPROJ"]}"
   #target: "#{ENV["TARGET"]}" # replace with your main target, required if you have more than one non-test target
 )
 latest_build_number = latest_testflight_build_number(
   api_key: api_key,
   version: current_version,
   app_identifier: app_identifier
 )
 increment_build_number(
   build_number: (latest_build_number + 1),
 )
end

desc "Recreate the provisioning profiles so you can deploy to your device, release on fabric and push to app store"
  lane :renew_certificates do
    types = ["appstore"] #"development", "adhoc"
    app_identifier = app_identifier
    types.each do |type|
      remove_provisioning_profile(app_identifier: app_identifier, type: type)
    end
end

desc "Check certs and profiles"
lane :prepare_signing do |options|
 app_id = app_identifier
 api_key = lane_context[SharedValues::APP_STORE_CONNECT_API_KEY]
 
 profile_name = "#{ENV["PROVISIONING_PROFILES"]}" # replace with the name of your existing profile, or define a name for the profile that fastlane will create if it’s not found
 
 cert(
     api_key: api_key,
     keychain_path: ENV["KEYCHAIN_PATH"] # the path to the keychain where your certificates are stored
   )
 
 # main app profile
 sigh(
   api_key: api_key,
   app_identifier: app_id,
   provisioning_name: profile_name,
   force: true # always recreate this exact profile to ensure it's valid and not expired
 )
 profile_name = match_type = Actions.lane_context[SharedValues::SIGH_NAME]
end

lane :build_release do |options|
 app_identifier = app_identifier
 output_name = "#{ENV["PRODUCE_APP_NAME"]}" # specify the name of the .ipa file to generate
 export_method = "app-store" # specify the export method
 compile_bitcode = true # specify whether to enable bitcode

# turn off automatic signing during build so correct code signing identity is guaranteed to be used
 update_code_signing_settings(
  use_automatic_signing: false,
  targets: ["#{ENV["TARGET"]}"], # specify which targets to update code signing settings for
  code_sign_identity: app_certificate, # replace with name of code signing identity if different
  bundle_identifier: app_identifier,
  build_configurations: [app_schema], # only toggle code signing settings for Release configurations
  profile_name: profile_name
 )

 gym(
  scheme: app_schema, # replace with name of your project’s scheme
  output_name: output_name,
  # sdk: "iphoneos",
  clean: true,
  configuration: app_schema,
 export_options: {
  method: export_method,
  provisioningProfiles: {
  app_identifier => profile_name
 },
  compileBitcode: compile_bitcode,
  xcargs: "ASSETCATALOG_COMPILER_APPICON_NAME=./Fastlane/Fastlane/Image Assest/Fastlane.xcassets/AppIcon.appiconset",
  codesigning_identity: app_certificate,
}
)

end

lane :upload_release do
api_key = lane_context[SharedValues::APP_STORE_CONNECT_API_KEY]

deliver(
 api_key: api_key,
 skip_screenshots: true,
 skip_metadata: true,
 skip_app_version_update: true,
 force: true, # skips verification of HTML preview file (since this will be run from a CI machine)
 run_precheck_before_submit: false # not supported through ASC API yet
)
end

lane :upload_build_to_testflight do
 load_asc_api_key
 # create_appicon
 fetch_and_increment_build_number
 renew_certificates
 prepare_signing
 build_release
 upload_release
end

end
```

Also i tried with pod deintegrate and install the pods using **arch -x86_64 pod install**
Can anyone help to resolve this error?

**This configuration works perfectly and able to generate build successfully in local machine and virtual mac**

Thanks in advance

Comment: Did you find a solution for this in the meantime?

Comment: Did anyone find the solution on this issue?

Answer (score 1):

Problem from the keychain is not unlock.

You need to unlock that by

```
security unlock-keychain
```

Or with password (run below code before trigger build ios)

```
security unlock-keychain -p <password>
```

Hope this way can help you, thanks.

Comment: Hello all,
Can we done edit app functionalities using fastlane?

Comment: @KevalGajjar: Nope hahaa. Unforgettable, this problem become the  permission when you trying to build from the other thread terminal. Not in the main thread account. So the problem will keeping error if you use fastlane on jenkins. And working fine if you use on terminal in that macos machine.

Comment: Hello folks, How can we bypass the 2FA while generating the build from jenkins?, as currently it's not working and from local terminal it's working fine but it is not working from jenkins.

Comment: @KevalUnchadiya: you can use `security unlock-keychain` with `-p` option.

Comment: it's not working i have checked that before

Comment: Did anyone have any other solution on this above issue. I tried with above commands even though its not working.